# How create form Html in Django_rest_framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

My Views is :

```
class TweetsListApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Tweet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TweetListSerializer
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'components/form.html'
```

Serializers:

```
class TweetListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_likes')
    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = ['id','content','likes']
    
    def get_likes(self,request):
        return random.randint(0,9999)
```

form.html

```
{% load rest_framework %}

<form method='Post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Add</button>
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
path('tweets/',TweetsListApiView.as_view()),
```

Is it possible to have from one viewclass class `TweetsListApiView`
standart Rest Page and HTML page where I creating new Tweet. if no
what the best way to create this html using serializer and Django REST